# How to condition an installation script in Oracle Apex based on a substitution string?

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to condition the execution of an Oracle Apex installation or upgrade script based on the value in a substitution string. I have 2 different scripts that populate seed data in the database and I want to condition which one is executed based on a value I specify for a substitution string during installation. The value for the substitution string is prompted for as part of the application import. So far pretty standard stuff.
But, no matter how I specify the condition I can't get it to work. None of the sample applications seem to have this type of condition set up and I was unable to find any articles anywhere that discussed this use case. Oracle's documentation on the topic is non-existent.

I have tried PL/SQL expressions of the form:
`:IMPLEMENTATION = 'MYVALUE'
&IMPLEMENTATION. = 'MYVALUE'
IMPLEMENTATION = 'MYVALUE'`

SQL Expression:
`select null from dual where :IMPLEMENTATION = 'DTEDDTM'`

Text in Expression 1 = Expression 2:
`IMPLEMENTATION, MYVALUE
:IMPLEMENTATION, 'MYVALUE'
&IMPLEMENTATION., 'MYVALUE'`

I tried a few other options but you get the idea. No matter what I try, even though the substitution string, IMPLEMENTATION, is set to 'MYVALUE' the script never gets executed.

Question #1: 
Is it even possible to access the value in a substitution string in an installation script condition?
Question #2: If "yes" to #1 then how?

Thank you.

Comment: Think you install your script with sqlplus .. so &IMPLEMENTATION. = 'MYVALUE' should be the syntax to substitude variables https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/sqlplus-101-substitution-variables#2

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I tried that and it didn't work. Please see my examples above.

Comment: I'd have to test, but I don't believe you can access substitutions strings during installation. This facility was really meant to query the data dictionary and custom data. My question to you is: what are you using to determine the value to put in the substitution string? When do you set the value to 'DTEDDTM' vs another value?

Comment: This is done during app installation. It is one of the strings prompted for as part of the installation.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the exported app SQL /I realized that the substitution strings are not made local to the script and therefore cannot be used to drive installation script conditions.
My solution was to create a short SQL*Plus script to populate a key/value pair in a setup table where I could store the implementation code. By running that script prior to importing the Apex application I could setup a condition to query the setup table, using the key, "IMPLEMENTATION", as the query qualification to retrieve the desired implementation. If that query returned a row then the installation script would be executed.
It works.